# trying to download with curl but can't decode the download url string

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download with curl from this url:

```
http://utorrent.en.softonic.com/download
```

When I select the alternative download link with my php script, I get this url:

```
http://utorrent.en.softonic.com/download-tracker?th=1%2F6CH9aeXedl4L8u%2BBHNJXWTW%2BLP1LFlnGQpxqjlxAMoVKXinh0rsXkMa8DN%2Bu6VBtArq5kfHl7Y2RJqLz%2FQUFTYOfbBsY4c9edz4d0uBydqkfciVN7cTFTjgf%2BVtTnzLV%2F4y3COCfojCKefPsPrRevbDp7d8SrrFDue95ZjhblKzCHHqpNk5gpQMihnZewg%2Fyc95fQne0DfkIfh%2BifbqX%2FCBkTDiekrGjfGamf9P%2BEll7oSfXnb9SLZg9H76ancy%2BinY3u8GE7HAJTsmqcaD4WPGon5rZYcnS8aljq7CPWLxysaKFOBu0VTr99hDNv%2Fd6rsepVexoymYrP2Hg6pe3strNwvWWePZXBsmekvAGt76yLP8R3mo5nqoBKu497L%2Fz4yQ%2BQCySXk9eqDKSE0MjByPorUPuqXZ9EMmi1KtSqX6HFvg6moZrG9Eg46eNZAY%2F9jhm6NhCV51pF6kWsnBtg4UfBJLKpQFLElRSt5vYfOQ7GE44TTPD7DpmF4XAZioF0ceMqr%2BEzZ6b3N1LY1Pwjsg7EYiTIyUmRtzKsI8WS7HB51H3bJqzF2HhUdVYVJt5U33G9VF0%2FwykMd7eJ%2FY5p6Ia6MmkpoWbe29UB3TzbVPUc%2F0t4wc8R2qkZK7Cqx5vvm3rCPViTpOQiq4ItJNTkM7DYamDyIpice8VB%2Fm7SBM9SOboRDewuQTNEDrIw3yGjfakXSGvFTeAS6j35ikg%3D%3D
```

but curl is downloading empty files. At the beginning I thought it was a bad config but I've tryed the url in the browser and it doesn't work, so finally I've figured they are using some kind of codification for the url but I have no idea which one because I'm very stuck in this domain. I've been checking the traffic with httpfox and there is a 302 redirect, curl is configured to follow redirects and after reading a lot of posts about curl config here, I think everything is ok on this side.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$output_filename = "test.exe";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $downloadUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $previousUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $dl=curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

$fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
            fwrite($fp, $result);
            fclose($fp);
            die('download complete');
```

So my question is does anybody know what kind of codification is using this url string and how can I decode it?

Comment: There are possibly some checks in place (so that you see their ads), namely a `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` set.

Comment: The download links also seem to have expirations (to prevent hotlinking).  You'll probably need to first fetch the main program page, parse out the download link and then request it.  The links may depend on cookies as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and working:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://utorrent.en.softonic.com/download';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2450.0 Iron/46.0.2450.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($result);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$link  = $xpath->query('//*[@id="download-button"]');

if ($link->length == 0) {
    die('Failed to find download link on page');
}

$url = $link->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// TODO: check HTTP response code and result for errors

file_put_contents('/tmp/utorrent.exe', $result);
```

Comment: don't know how to thank you. I'll take a closer look at that dom document class because I would like to understand more in dept how is this done!

Comment: It seemed like a better idea to use DOM than trying to find the link using regular expressions.  DOMDocument parses the HTML using `loadHtml` so the page is available in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) format.  This allows us to use XPath to query the document for the element with an `id` of `download-button` (this is a `<a>` tag with the download link) so the request could then me made to download the file.  With anything but the simplest HTML matching, its better to use DOM to extract and find information on a page.